# Creating a working game with Unity3D?

Tags: unity

I recently start learning Unity3D and following VTC's video tutorials and others tutorial, so far i've found it very easy to work it and to create stuff, i havent got to the part where i need to script anything YET.

While i still havent hit the scripting part yet i did like to ask:

- Do i really need to script anything to
  make a simple game with it ? (why am i asking this ? until now from the tutorials i've been watching it seems that unity3d has most of the physics and codes needs to create a working version of a simple game, for example making falling crates, the rigidbody functions, it taking into account flags and grass being touched by the wind and moving)
- What are some simple examples of
  where will i be scripting for ? (just wondering if there will be something to script for even for a simple game and what would that be)
- When i build the finish project will it compile everything as if it was a VS project and make a working version without the need of any other wrappers for it is data, etc ? (this is sort of self replied by their webpage but i just wanted to confirm if i got this right)

*I am aware those might be subjective questions but while i am unexperienced with it and havent found anything related to those questions yet or havent meet the end of a project to be able to confirm for myself i would like to receive some advices and information in regards this.*

**PS: i did a search but i was not sure of what should i look for to find answer for this kinda of questions so if this is a duplicate of any sort let me know and i will delete it once i am pointed out for the duplicate.**

Best regards.

Comment: Off question, is unity3d tag symbolic link to unity or so ? i've tried to change it from unity to unity3d afew times but it does not work.

Comment: The official name of the engine is Unity. Unity3D is just their website.

Comment: i see so unity3d is indeed a symbolic link here that goes back to unity thanks.

Comment: Start getting your hands dirty, otherwise you won't understand how the system is working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Yes you will need to script things.  Everything is done through scripting.  They do have really basic scripts you can use instead of writing your own for some common things like a first person controller, but they don't have any kind of graphical logic editor or anything like that.
- You'll need to script any game logic, enemy behavior, probably player input, menus, which animations to play, when to spawn entities... really anything other than the core foundational stuff they provide like physics and importing assets and such.
- Building a unity app is done entirely through their interface (other than for the iPhone and consoles).  So you go to the build settings window, say "I want to make a web version", hit build, and it spits out a preliminary HTML file and a .unity3d file.  For the mac builds it spits out a .app, and for windows it spits out a .exe and a folder with all the compiled data in it.

Really the best thing to do is download the free/indie version and play around with it.

Comment: That is what i am doing right now ;P i was making some 2d game and finished it but i had lot of logic, work and calculations to do... But while i was for example adding the first player controller or sun light etc it seems so easy and i had not much to do other then setting up the settings hehe. Hmmm the builder is then just like i was wondering it would act like. Thanks a lot for the answer ... +1 you deverse the cookie...